# dbwriteTable incompatible with other schemas

Tags: r, jdbc, rodbc, rjdbc, roracle

I am not sure if this question has surfaced before but i am not able to write data to a different other than mine using dbwriteTable() even if i have write access to others schema.

Below are the things i have tried

```
dbWriteTable(conn=,name= "SCHEMA.TABLE",df,overwrite=T,append=T,row.names=F)
dbWriteTable(conn=,name= "schema.table",df,overwrite=T,append=T,row.names=F)
dbWriteTable(conn=,name= c("SCHEMA","TABLE"),df,overwrite=T,append=T,row.names=F)
```

Let me know if i am doing something wrong

Comment: What happens when you run your code? Any errors?

Comment: Hi Robert.. the error says..can't append to non-existing table ,even when i have the table in database

Comment: to be precise ..Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) : 
  execute JDBC update query failed in dbSendUpdate (ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Answer (score 0):

In `ROracle` `dbWritetable` there is param `schema`

```
dbWriteTable(conn, name, value, row.names = FALSE, overwrite = FALSE,
             append = FALSE, ora.number = TRUE, schema = NULL, date = FALSE, ...)
```

> schema     A case-sensitive character string specifying a schema name (or
>   a vector of character strings for dbListTables).

You need to specify it